# lualatexja-preset, baselineshift has no effect when used in LibreOffice TexMath

Tags: latex, libreoffice-writer

I use TexMath and laulatexja-preset to insert more complex pieces of text in LibreOffice writer. In itself this works well but the only drawback is that in TexMath the option \ltjsetparameter{yjabaselineshift=0pt} has no effect.
In TexStudio the following code gives this (correct) result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs} 
\usepackage[noto,fontspec,match]{luatexja-preset}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage[]{mdframed}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\ltjsetparameter{yjabaselineshift=0pt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily
    \begin{equation*}
        \tcboxmath[size=small, colback=white, sharp corners=all]{
            \text{い-adj(\sim}\cancel{\text{い}})\to\text{\sim}\text{さ}\\ 
        } 
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In LO Writer, the same code gives this result

[image]

As you can see, the Japanese characters do not align with the other characters. Changing the value for yjabaselineshift has no effect in Writer.

Some time ago I asked in the LibreOffice forums if someone knew how to fix this but I didn't get answer.

I would appreciate any help from this forum.

Comment: Can you show both .log files?

Comment: Which .log files? I found a .log file for the texstudio version but that is 1650 lines long. I didn't find a .log for the LO Writer example.